# Map Tiles are not loaded after doing anything with the MapView in Android Google Maps

Tags: java, android, android-maps, android-mapview

I have a problem with the MapView. Here's my scenario:

1. I can successfully create the MapActivity. The initial google maps is loaded. Everything works just fine.
2. After clicking on the map, trying to move it (or actually do anything), the map tiles are not loaded anymore. And it looks like on the image.

I have already found plenty of threads about not setting the Api Key correctly or whatever. I ensure you, that I have set this correctly (otherwise, the map wouldn't be loaded at all). Does anyone have a solution for this. The Api Level I am using is 8, and I am trying it for android 2.2 in the default emulator. Thanks.

Here is a snippet from the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application ...
```

Here is the layout file:

```
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="..." >
    </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
```

[image]

Here is the code from the activity, where I initialize the mapView:

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.setStreetView(true);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

It also has a LocationListener, that just animates to the location it receives.

Comment: Show your Activity code @Filip Majernik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the API key and check `mapView.setStreetView();` :)

Comment: API Key is definitely correct. What do you mean by check setStreetView? I have that set to tru.

Comment: Try setting it to `false` and check if the issue persists.

Comment: That really did the trick(any explanation?). However, the map is still not displayed when I set the location from the emulator and call controller.animateTo(). Any ideas about that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#setStreetView(boolean)

MapView will not allow you to display Street View, only 2D map. Especially not on emulator :)

Comment: Regarding the changed location, are you sure your `onLocationChanged()` method is called when you send coordinates through the DDMS? I hope `controller.animateTo()` is placed there.

Comment: Yes, everythings is fine. I've found out, that I accidently used latitude in both coordinates, so that problem is solved. Thank you anyway.